# Grid With Auto Margin - Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

I have this XAML code and I want the grid to be in row 2 and Column 1-3.
Now the problem is if I specify the margin of grid, it doesn't look good with devices of different sizes and if I don't specify margin, the grid goes out of the mobile screen.

How to keep the margin auto and grid inside the layout

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <Button x:Name="undoButton" 
            Content="undo" 
            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Click="undoButton_Click" Height="70" Width="90" 
            FontSize="16" Background="#FF4B9599" />
    <Button x:Name="redoButton" Content="redo" 
            Height="70" 
            Width="90"
            Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
            Click="redoButton_Click"  FontSize="16" 
            Background="#FF4B9599"/>
    <Button x:Name="clearButton" 
            Content="clear" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            Height="70" Width="90"
            Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2"
            FontSize="16"  Background="#FF4B9599" 
            Click="clearButton_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is the definition of rows and columns:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="90" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

There is the grid if I don't add margin

[image]

Comment: didn't Understand your question, can you be more specific.Please include some drawings for the expected result.

Comment: @Joseph please check the screenshot now I hope it is clear

Comment: What other elements you have inside the Grid?

Comment: try changing  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  for undoButton and  HorizontalAlignment="Left" for clearButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have provided us, 
the solution would be pretty simple

Replace this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="90" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

with this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="90" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

If you give us more information of the desired result and the other items you want to put in row 0 and row 1, we can give more specific help to you.

Comment: No it doesn't Work. but I appreciate the help Thank you :)

Comment: * , '9*' & '*' worked. before I did not knew how it works but now I understand it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what the problem was or where it was but this worked

```
 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="80"/>
 <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="70" />
```